# One view, Two options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I am building a forum and I have a question page (having all the question).

Going in the question details page I have an **edit question** link for each question and I have an **edit answer** link for all the answers as well.

The difference between them would be when I click the edit for the question I would like to have my title in the text box but when I click edit on the answer I would like to have my title in the label.

What would be the best practice: Build different Views with two Model Views or do it in one View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General guidance for MVC is no business logic in view. And this sounds like it could be business logic.

Of course if most of the views are common that can be factored out into a partial they both use.

Answer (score 0):

That might be not the best practice but might be a good solution:

Model:

```
public partial class QuestionAnswer
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string DisabledQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditQuestion()
{
    DisabledQuestioon = true;
    return View("QuestionAnswer");
}

public ActionResult EditAnswer()
{
    DisabledQuestioon = false;
    return View("QuestionAnswer");
}
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Question, new { (model.DisabledQuestion ? @readonly = "readonly" : null) })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Answer)
```